# Why is the exact keyword not working on NavLink?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I can't get the route to display by itself. How do I get the exact key to work?

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  NavLink,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Job from "./job";

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
    <Router>
        <Job/>   
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login}></Route>
    </Router>
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Job.js

```
<NavLink exact={true} to='/' activeClassName="active-link">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add `<Switch />` component as well, see from the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch):

> Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location.

Try as the following:

```
<Router>
    <Job/>
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" component={Login}></Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<NavLink to='/' exact activeClassName="activeLink" activeStyle={{
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "red"   }}>Job</NavLink>
```

try this code.